# How can I change between different color schemes in vi?

Tags: linux, vi

How can I change between different color schemes in vi?

Comment: IMHO, here's the **[best answer (link)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3975649/729513)**

Answer (score 10):

you could try different color schemes like this:

https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1565/Enabling+vi+syntax+colors#gs

My problem was only deep blue comment color in default color scheme, so I changed just that:

```
cd ~
vi .vimrc
highlight comment ctermfg=lightblue
```

or change lightblue to cyan or whatever

Comment: heh. this is exactly what i wanted to do when i googled this. the default comment color is too dark.

Comment: may i know beside comment, any other syntax available for me to change? And where could I get the available colour list?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, plain ol' vi doesn't provide different colorschemes. If you are using vim however, you can type `:colorscheme <newcolorscheme>`. You can use tab to cycle through the installed colorschemes.

See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switch_color_schemes for more information